# What is the matrix of the iSwap gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

Mostly I'm confused over whether the common convention is to use +$i$ or -$i$ along the anti-diagonal of the middle $2\times 2$ block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Mostly I'm confused over whether the common convention is to use +i or
>   -i along the anti-diagonal of the middle 2x2 block.

The former. There are two $+i$'s along the anti-diagonal of the middle $2\times 2$ block of the iSWAP gate. See page 95 [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-84628-887-6_2)<sup>[$\dagger$]</sup>.

[image]

[$\dagger$]: *Explorations in Computer Science (Quantum Gates)* - Colin P. Williams

Answer (score 6):

Whether you use $+i$ or $-i$ is entirely up to you.  After all, your definition of $\pm i$ is merely a convention.  On the other hand, I think I've only ever seen it with $+i$.

On a more general footing, you can consider that iSWAP is the gate obtained by time-evolving with an XX interaction ($H=-\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x - \sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y$), in which case it depends on which sign of $i$ in the Schrödinger equation and for the Hamiltonian you prefer.  (You get $+i$ if you evolve with $\exp[-iHt]$, $t=\pi/4$, and chose the minus sign in the Hamiltonian as above, i.e. a ferromagnet).

Comment: You're right that if you *globally* replace +i by -i in every single gate, that all measurement expectations are identical. But typically you'd be combining the iswap with other existing gates that already have a convention (e.g. $S = \text{diag}(1, i)$), in which case the choice of +i vs -i for the iswap has observable consequences. [Here's an example circuit with that property.](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={"cols":[["H","H"],["~lnpf"],["H","H"],["Z^½"],["X","•"],[1,"H"]],"gates":[{"id":"~lnpf","name":"iSwap","matrix":"{{1,0,0,0},{0,0,i,0},{0,i,0,0},{0,0,0,1}}"}]})

Comment: @CraigGidney Sure. But then, again, it depends how you define your other gates, such as $Z^{1/2}$, for which different conventions might be used as well.  In practice, for gates which come from a time evolution (such as iSWAP) the 2-qubit gates are likely the ones which fix the choice of $i$, since it is typically easy to reverse the sign of one-qubit Hamiltonians but not of two-qubit Hamiltonians.

Comment: Mathematically, the operation of conjugating all complex numbers is a [non-trivial field automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism#Examples) of $\mathbb{C}$ that fixes $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, all measurement expectations remain fixed under this symmetry. There do exist other automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$, but they are [wild](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers/412034)...